# How to break and continue work in nested for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, break, continue

I am trying to produce the sum of numbers in a string.

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < str.length() - 1; j++) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j))) {
       i = j;
       break;
     } else if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j + 1))) {
        continue;
     }
     sum += Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, j + 1));
   }
 }
 return sum;
}
```

For example, if I have `sumNumbers("aa11b33")` it should return `44`. However, it's returning `11`.

I'm assuming this is because the outer loop is terminating due to the `break` or `continue` statements. Is that the problem? If so, what should I do?

Comment: 1. `continue` and `break` only affect the directly enclosing loop 2. Step through your code using a debugger to see why it isn't working properly

Comment: *"I'm assuming this is because the outer loop is terminating due to the `break` or `continue` statements."* Nope. Rather than guessing, use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement-by-statement and watch exactly what it does.